# Нужна в помощь с Regex'ом в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое задание: нам дано определенный текст, и нам нужно удалить слова которые имеют n-длинну и начинаются на согласную букву.
У меня получился вот такой regex:

```
"[\\s]?\\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\\w\\-']{" + (WORD_LENGTH - 1) + "}\\b"
```

Где WORD_LENGTH - это длинна слов, которых нужно удалить.

но проблема следующая, если у нас будет предложение, например

```java
"tool that you can use to your advantage. It is, therefore, wise to explore the"
```

то в результате получится:

```java
" you can use to advantage. It is, therefore, to explore the"
```

То есть в результате лишний пробел, как можно избавиться от него?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам хочется всё сделать в регулярном выражении, придётся повторить шаблоны для того, чтобы отдельно найти совпадение в начале строки (тогда надо захватить и пробелы справа) и в её конце:

```
^(?:\s*\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\w\-']{3})+\s*|\s*\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\w\-']{3}\b(?:\s+$)?
```

В коде можно использовать переменную:

```
String tokenRegex = "[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\\w\\-']{" + (WORD_LENGTH - 1) + "}";
String regex = "^(?:\\s*\\b" + tokenRegex + ")+\\s*|\\s*\\b" + tokenRegex + "\\b(?:\\s+$)?";
```

Чтобы не удалять переносы на новую строку, нужно заменить `\s` на `\h`.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/f8n9IT/1).

Answer (score 0):

Проще использовать `String::trim` для удаления лишних пробелов в начале строки после замены.

Также можно использовать более короткую запись регулярного выражения для определения согласных букв в начале слова (на английском) с флагом `(?i)` для игнорирования регистра:

```java
public static String fix(int len, String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("(?i)\\s*\\b[b-z&&[^eiou]][\\w\\-']{" + (len - 1) + "}\\b", "")
              .trim();
}
```

```java
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", 
    fix(4, "Tool that you can use to your advantage. It is, therefore, wise to explore the DOOM.")
);
// 'you can use to advantage. It is, therefore, to explore the.'
```